# Are reference objects with different types any different in Java?

Tags: java, oop, reference, polymorphism, compile-time

When saying:

```
  String str = "hello";
  Object obj = str;
  System.out.println(str==obj);
```

The result is true, because it points to the same objects in memory, which makes sense. But if I say:

```
obj.indexOf("h");
```

Or any subclass method, I get "cannot find symbol". They're still pointing to the same object, so what's going on during compile-time that makes reference objects of different types different from each other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Object` type reference only knows about methods that are part of its public interface.

You have to cast if you know that `Object` reference is a `String` type:

```
int index = ((String) obj).indexOf("h");
```

Comment: Cool, so is does this checking at compile-time only serve the purpose to catch bugs before runtime? Or does it serve a more significant purpose for the compiler/JVM?

Comment: @rb612 Nope. If `obj` is of type `Object`, the compiler cannot know the exact type of the value stored in that variable. Now, if you know that `obj` contains a `String` at compile time, you can tell the compiler "this is actually a `String`" - the compiler does not know this, so you must tell it. If it's not actually a `String`, but you try telling the compiler it is, a `ClassCastException` would be thrown at runtime. Downcasting is for compile-time development

Comment: @VinceEmigh that makes a lot of sense! Thanks! So when we get a try an invalid cast, even if we aren't actually calling a method that the class doesn't have, we get a `ClassCastException`. We're not actually encountering an error, are we, because if we just say `int number = "hello"`, we're not actually calling an integer method on the string, but we still get that exception. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Apples and Pears.

The identity check == is performed **at runtime**. And valid and fine.

The construct `obj.indexOf...` is a **compile time error** as class Object just does not have a method `indexOf`

If you tell the compiler (by means of casting) that obj contains a String, you can get valid code

```
((String)obj).indexOf("h");
```

Will compile again